# Synonymize [mfp] and [printer-scanner] with [multi-function-printer]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Thanks to Burgi, [mfp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mfp) (10 Q's) now has a definition (and some more questions).  Unfortunately, whoever originally created the tag opted for cryptic.  Suggest making it a synonym of a new tag: [multi-function-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-function-printer) for those who might get brain freeze while looking for the right tag.  I'm suggesting using the spelled-out tag as the primary.

Also, we have another existing tag: [printer-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-scanner) (22 Q's) which refers to the same thing.  So that would also get synonomized with [multi-function-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-function-printer).

Comment: I tried looking for [tag:multi-function-printer] but couldn't find it. I didn't think to actually create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [mfp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mfp) and [printer-scanner](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/printer-scanner) have been merged and synonymised with [multi-function-printer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-function-printer).

I copied over the wiki excerpt as well for a bit of context.